# pure Javascript callback issue

Tags: javascript, callback, jasmine

I have the following two methods in my code:

```
    this.getUserForTest = function(usedPhoneNumber, userShouldBeRegistered, done) {
userShouldBeRegistered);
    getUser(usedPhoneNumber, function (isExist) {
        if(isExist === !userShouldBeRegistered) {
            usedPhoneNumber++;
            _that.getUserForTest(usedPhoneNumber, userShouldBeRegistered, done);
        } else {
            _that.testedPhoneNumber = usedPhoneNumber;
            console.log("found user number: " + usedPhoneNumber);
            deleteUserRegistrationAttmepts(_that.testedPhoneNumber, done);
        }
    });
};

this.cleanUpUser = function (phone, done) {
    loginUser(phone, function(userLoggedIn) {
        if (userLoggedIn === true) {
            getOauthToken(phone, function(gotOuth) {
                if (gotOuth === true) {
                    deleteUser(phone, done);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

these methods are part of the jasmine test suite we are running through the following command:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
        e2eHelperMethods.getUserForTest(initPhoneNumber, false, done);
        browser.get(e2eHelperMethods.defaultWebsiteUri);
    });

    afterEach(function (done) {
        e2eHelperMethods.cleanUpUser(e2eHelperMethods.testedPhoneNumber, done);
    });
```

when I try to join the two methods like the following example i receive an error which probably means that i am having some async issues:

```
this.cleanUpAndGetTestUser = function (phone, userShouldBeRegistered, done) {
    _that.cleanUpUser(phone, function(isDone) {
        if (isDone === true) {
            _that.getUserForTest(phone, userShouldBeRegistered, done);
        }
    });
};
```

I will be very grateful if someone can point me to the issue at hand - there must be a callback thingy i forgot...

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: None - process exists